# Различие define и const

Tags: c++

В чем различие между этими определениями переменной:

```
#define N 100
```

и

```
const int n = 100;
```

Что из этих двух является более предпочтительным и в чем достоинства каждого?

Comment: Можно сокращать куски нудного кода что повторяется этим, очень помогает

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Это очень дискуссионный вопрос у всех. Но в целом, в C++ лучше использовать `const` везде, где это возможно.

Плюсы:

- на них действуют области видимости.
- компилятор относится к ним как к обычными переменным, доступным только на чтение.
- у них есть тип.

У `#define` это все - недостатки. Они действуют от места определения и до ... конца. Хотя, где этот конец будет - ещё нужно хорошо подумать.  Они могут переопределять друг дружку и иногда искать, где именно было в очередной раз переопределено - ещё то удовольствие. Компилятор часто выдает очень "загадочные ошибки". Классический пример с макросом `min/max`. Файл `<windows.h>` определяет их. И может быть очень весело. Детали - [NOMINMAX](https://support.microsoft.com/help/143208/prb-using-stl-in-windows-program-can-cause-min-max-conflicts).

Ещё у `#define` есть большой недостаток - это то, что некоторые думают, что там есть скобки. А их нет.

```
#define add(a,b) a+b

if (add(x,y) * add(x,y)) {}
```

кажется, что будет посчитано `(x+y)` в квадрате. А на самом деле - .... на самом деле `x+y + x*y`.

Но мы немного отвлеклись. Такого сделать обычным `const` уже нельзя. Но легко сделать `inline` функциями. И их результат будет предсказуемый.

Поэтому:

- eсли нужно просто определить константу - используйте `const` (даже само слово намекает).
- eсли нужно определить макрос - используйте функции (если хочется интересней - используйте `inline`, но компиляторы сейчас достаточно умные).
- если нужно усложнить код и добавить синтаскического сахара - тогда самое время использовать `#define`.

**UPD**

А ещё хорошо найти книгу [Эффективное использование C++. 55 верных советов улучшить структуру и код ваших программ - Скотт Майерс](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2610625/) и почитать второй совет (в любом случае - там всю книгу можно читать и читать).

Comment: И все же я больше люблю `#define` ... (иногда с ними можно делать нетривиальные вещи в др. макросах)

Comment: Это как goto - если умеешь - чудесный инструмент. Если нет... то можно ногу отстрелить и не заметить.

Comment: @KoVadim и всё же #define может существенно помочь сократить код, я им часто шаблонные не самодостаточные конструкции сокращаю (например .first до .F в pair<>)

Comment: Ноги целы? Руки на месте?:)

Comment: (Выступая в роли адвоката дьявола). "У них есть тип"? Но у `#define`-констант тоже есть тип, особенно пока речь идет о константах скалярных типов, т.е. литеральных константах. Например, `100` имеет тип `int`. Во многих случаях суффикс или явный каст поможет сделать тип литеральной `#define`-константы таким, какой нужен автору.

Comment: Переформулирую - у констант тип очевиден. У define - не всегда. В первом случае компилятор подскажет, а с define может легко проигнорировать.

Comment: @KoVadim: Под "очевиден" вы имеет в виду, что среднестатистический кодер умеет читать тип в `const int`, но не обладет достаточными знаниями, чтобы определить тип `0xFF`? Или что-то другое? А что касается "проигнорировать", то правила narrowing conversions в C++ как раз и сформулитрованы так, чтобы тип "иногорировался" именно и только там, где его *уместно* игнорировать.

Comment: это слишком тривиальный случай. А вот как такой `#define a sin(` и `#define b )` и использование `cout << a 1 b;` (зачем такое нужно - не спрашивайте, но внутрях видового апи и буста такого добра в концентрированном виде много. Я просто сильно упростил)

Comment: "на самом деле x+y + x*y" - может Вы имели ввиду: " x+y*x+y " ??!

Comment: @Wladimir, математически это одно и то же.

Comment: Ссылка на NOMINMAX больше не работает.

Answer (score 9):

В чистом языке С++, если у вас есть выбор между этими двумя вариантами, то ясно, что предпочтительным является именно вариант с `const`. Однако вопрос задан несколько ограничивающе, ибо почему-то предложены к рассмотрению только эти два способа. В рамках современного языка С++ у вас есть третий способ

```
constexpr int N = 100;
```

который фактически является унифицированным вариантом, специально предназначенным для создания *констант времени компиляции*, как именованных, так и вычислимых.

В данном случае, если не лезть в иррелевантные детали, разницы между `const` и `constexpr` не будет, однако существует мнение, что использование `constexpr` предпочтительнее именно в вашем варианте - когда вас интересует именно константа времени компиляции, но совершенно не интересует ее адресная идентичность, т.е. вы никогда не будете рассматривать *адрес* этой константы. Вариант с `const` в рамках этого мнения условно "отодвигается" на роли, которые этот квалификатор играет в языке С, т.е. создание "неизменяемых переменных" в памяти.

Но, опять же, такое различие существует лишь на уровне соглашений, т.е. разницы между `const int` и `constexpr int` в тривиальных применениях вы не заметите.

Однако и у `#define` тоже есть свои преимущества.

Ограничение на использование *только* либо `const`, либо `#define` варианта возникнет тогда, когда вы будете создавать кросс-компилируемый С и С++ код (например, заголовочные файлы библиотек, предназначенных для использования в обоих языках). Тогда вам в большинстве случаев придется пользоваться именно `#define`, ибо в языке С квалификатор `const` не создает констант. В языке С для создания именованных констант времени компиляции у вас есть только `enum` и `#define`.

В качестве еще одного преимущества варианта с `#define` можно назвать очевидную (но часто забываемую) возможность использовать `#define`-константы в условных выражениях препроцессора, т.е. в `#if`. Ни `const`, ни `constexpr` вам там не помогут. Шаблонное метапрограммирование и появление в языке С++ таких C++17 свойств, как "static if" (`if constexpr`) тоже частично переносит такие применения из области препроцессора в область самого языка и, соответственно, снижает ценность `#define`-констант в С++, но тем не менее эта деталь тоже заслуживает упоминания.

Comment: [Нередкая](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A187690+is%3Aa+const+define) эта тема у вас однако :)

Comment: @vp_arth: Не должно быть больше 2-3 постов, да и те скорее по С, а не по С++.